# Microsoft Azure Auth Error

Tags: python, python-3.x, azure, autoscaling

I'm learning Microsoft Azure and using python3. I got following error code :

```
C:\Python\python.exe D:/Phyton/Restapi/a.py
Cannot find resource group sgelastic. Check connection/authorization.
{
  "error": {
    "code": "AuthorizationFailed",
    "message": "The client '22273c48-3d9d-4f31-9316-210135595353' with object id '22273c48-3d9d-4f31-9316-210135595353' does not have authorization to perform action 'Microsoft.Resources/subscriptions/resourceGroups/read' over scope '/subscriptions/0f3e0eec-****-****-b9f9-************resourceGroups/sgelastic'."
  }
}

Process finished with exit code 0
```

What should ı do? I should create new subscription or something else?
Thank you.

Comment: Your description is not clear. Could you post more details? Such as what you want to do, your source code of `a.py`, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Laurent Mazuel said, try to follow the steps as the figure below to add the necessary permission.

[image]

1. Click the `Subscription` tab on Azure portal.
2. Select the subscription of the related resource group.
3. Move to the `Access control (IAM)` tab.
4. Click the `+ Add` button.
5. Select the role like `Contributor` in the `Add permission` dialog.
6. Search the name of your user or application, and select the one you used in the searched result list.
7. Save it.

Or you can use Azure CLI 2.0 to create service principal to do it.

```
az ad sp create-for-rbac --role="Contributor" --scopes="/subscriptions/mySubscriptionID/resourceGroups/myResourceGroupName"
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

The credentials you are using have not the necessary permissions to read the resource group "sgelastic".
You can add the "contributor" role to these credentials, or a more precise permission to this specific resource group, depending of your needs.

You should read the documentation on RBAC on Azure for that, current is there:
https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/active-directory/role-based-access-control-what-is

The list of available actions (and name of built-in roles that have it) is there:
https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/active-directory/role-based-access-built-in-roles